# Installation forcing the use of python static archive rather than shared object

Tags: python, linux, cmake

I've updated this question and the error it is giving me now, though I can't be certain whether I'm working towards or away from a solution, as I've little knowledge of cmake!

When trying to install a python program, I'm running into an error I'm uncertain how to fix. The program is as follows:

```
os.chdir("spenvis_csv")
if not os.path.exists("build"):
    os.mkdir("build")

os.chdir("build")
call("cmake ../", shell=True)
call("make")
os.chdir(loc_dir)
os.chdir("python_utilities")
if not os.path.exists("lib"):
    os.mkdir("lib")

for file_name in os.listdir("spenvis_csv/build/source"):
    if file_name.find("libSpenvis.") !=-1:
        shutil.move("spenvis_csv/build/source/%s" %   

(file_name),"lib/Spenvis.so") 
    os.chdir("..")
```

And the error output is as follows:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras original/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/spenvis_csv/build
Scanning dependencies of target Spenvis
[ 33%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/pySpenvisCSV.cc.o
[ 66%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/SpenvisCSV.cc.o
[100%] Building CXX object source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/SpenvisCSVCollection.cc.o
Linking CXX shared library libSpenvis.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib64/libpython2.7.a(abstract.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata.str1.8' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/local/lib64/libpython2.7.a: could not read symbols: Bad value
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [source/libSpenvis.so] Error 1
make[1]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Ah, and I'm definitely a cmake scrub. In the source directory, methinks, lies the actual CMakeLists.txt, which is as follows:

```
# Make sure the compiler can find include files
include_directories (${PYSPENVIS_SOURCE_DIR})

# get boost
set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
#set(Boost_USE_MULTIEADED ON)
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS
                python
             REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${Boost_LIBRARY_DIRS})

# get python
include(FindPythonLibs)

set(PythonLibs_USE_STATIC_LIBS   OFF)
find_package(PythonInterp)
find_package(PythonLibs)
include_directories(${PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
set_target_properties(${PYTHON_LIBRARIES} PROPERTIES POSITION_INDEPENDENT_CODE ON)


add_library(Spenvis  SHARED pySpenvisCSV.cc SpenvisCSV.cc SpenvisCSVCollection.cc)
TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(Spenvis ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${PYTHON_LIBRARIES})
```

With special attention to those last few lines, as those were the lines I've edited to point towards the correct libraries. However, now I'm getting  a new error:

```
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/smh/Linux/Desktop/gras-03-03/python/python_utilities/spenvis_csv/build
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/usr/lib64/lib64/libboost_python-mt.so.5', needed by `source/libSpenvis.so'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [source/CMakeFiles/Spenvis.dir/all] Error 2
make:
```

Particularly strange now is the **/usr/lib64/lib64/** , I'm not sure why it's trying to find that directory, as it doesn't exist.

I apologize for the length. I've omitted the Internal cache entries, but can post these as well if they would be of use.

Comment: show your `CMakeLists.txt`… how do you find a Python lib?

Comment: The file that seems to be working towards... something is a CmakeCache.txt file. Editing that gives me different errors, at least. I'll post them above, as a comment hasn't enough room.

Comment: CMakeCache.txt is generated from the the CMakeLists.txt file. It's a bad idea to edit the cache directly, as anything running cmake again will blindly remove it. The problem lies in CMakeLists.txt if anywhere in the cmake stuff. Everything stems from that.

Comment: I've added the CMakeLists.txt file instead. As I've said, I'm definitely not great with CMake!

Comment: Did you try installing 32-bit Python libraries, or building a 64-bit Spenvis library?

Comment: I /think/ I've moved on from this error. I'd answer my own question if I could tell you what I did to get away from it, but I can't. I'm also now having a different problem...!To avoid continually updating the question and making the title more irrelevant to the question than it already is, I'm just going to post a new question. Thanks for all the suggestions!